# How to get users that meet all of criteria for fields in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm working on a project using the MERN stack. I'm trying to have a function where the user inputs some data, and we'll return students that match with them based on their inputted criteria. For instance, if they put in that they want someone who is male, grade 12, and goes to school X, then we return all people who have a school field equal to school X, a grade field equal to 12, and a gender field equal to male. If it doesn't match any of those criteria, that user should be eliminated. Additionally, the user doesn't have to input all that data. So say they want to meet someone who is male and in grade 12, but doesn't care about their school, they can input just that and then we return all users that match just the grade and gender specifications. So far I've been able to return all users who match the grade specifications with the following code:

```
 const userProfiles = await User.find({}, { grade: profileFields.grade, grade: 1 });
```

However, I also want to make sure they meet the other specifications, and if the specifications for one of them is left blank, I still want to return the users that meet the rest of the specifications. I'd really appreciate any help, I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that `profileFields` is an object that carries all those crieteria you mentioned. E.g.

```
profileFields = {grade: 12, gender: 'M', school: 'X'};
```

Sometimes though, it may come in as:

```
profileFields = {grade: 12, gender: 'M' school: ''}; //school is missing, which means select all schools
```

All you need to do is assemble a find query from this object:

```
const query = {};
if(profileFields.grade)
    query.grade = profileFields.grade;

if(profileFields.gender)
    query.gender = profileFields.gender;

if(profileFields.school)
    query.school = profileFields.school;
```

So now, for example, if the use inputs `{grade: 12, gender: '', school: 'X'}`, your query fill look like this: `{grade: 12, school: 'X'}` and omit gender, which will tell mongodb to return all genders.

I can see you are using mongoose, so...

```
User.find(query)
    .then(users => {
        //Your matched users will be in variable users
        console.out(users)
    })
```

Note that I have made some assumptions here. For example that your User schema in fact has fields named `gender` `school` and `grade`. If the grade field is named, say, `user_grade`, then your query assembly will change to `query.user_grade = profileFields.grade`

Comment: This worked exactly as intended! Thank you so much for your detailed response it really means a lot to me. I now understand how this implementation works and will use it a lot as well going forward. Again, I sincerely appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: @richard59897 No problem Richard. Glad it helped.